# Dynamic Analysis Detection

Tags: ida, ida-plugin, dynamic-analysis

Suppose you want to conceal an application's true purpose from analysts by reacting to dynamic analysis tools. How is it possible to detect running (in debugger mode) the application under a reverse engineering tool (e.g., IDA Pro) by the application itself? What code do you propose to use while preparing the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**the easy answer:**

probably a Sleep(random()*60000 + 10000) is more than enough to thwat most dynamic analysis systems. Or if((int)(random()*10) == 8) and so on

**check for debuggers:**

The 'standard' way is to use [IsDebuggerPresent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms680345(v=vs.85).aspx). But analysis systems are aware of that and try to patch these calls. So there are similar approaches checking the field in the EPROCESS structure directly. I've also seen malware checking the result of [OutputDebugString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa363362(v=vs.85).aspx).

**check for analysis systems**

Some malware families employ checks for certain process names implying the system may be used for analysis, like the pcap driver or the names of debugger-processes. Also, the availability of certain libraries may prevent the program from exhibiting its real behavior.

**check for virtual environment**

There are already lots of papers about this. Most dynamic analysis of potentially malicious programs happens in virtual environments. There are different approaches you can take here:

- Timing traps - virtualization is slower than bare metal machines
- Undefined behavior - often virtualization tools respond differently in error situations (e.g. invalid opcodes)
- Suspicious strings - e.g. 'VirtualBox Harddrive', ...

Also, there are some very advanced approaches, like checking the behavior of the TLB.

Comment: Could you clarify what TLB is?

Comment: @Nordwald I actually did find the IsDebuggerPresent() routine in the assembly working with the DLL on IDA Pro. Regarding the random() in your answer, you meant rand()?

Comment: @Martin This may be of help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680581(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I found a few useful links. They had overlaps so I'll copy the major one here. https://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/windows-anti-debug-reference

Comment: @Martin TLB stands vor translation lookaside buffer and is an internal structure used by the CPU for caching physical addresses for virtual addresses

Comment: @Newbie IsDebuggerPresent() is the classic technique - IDA Pro already considers this. The same is true for OllyDbg with advanced options. Still, checking the value in other ways (e.g. reading the PEB) is still fesible. 'random()' is just a placeholder for a random number function of your choice ;)

Comment: @Nordwald Thank you for clarification. I guess it was a silly question to ask considering all the material on the web considering various categories of anti-debugging techniques; TLSCallBacks, Windows API, Timing, Exceptions, Traps to name a few. By the way any suggestion on how to deeply grasp these? There should be a starting point!

Comment: @Newbie People get creative with these techniques. For example, in order to detect a virtual analysis environment, you can check for mouse activity. Most of these techniques come from practice, but I guess the categories in my answer give a base outline. For example, early Bolek samples are weakly obfuscated and employ a range of these methods, but non too sophisticated